# How to create timer on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm creating workout timer app using rails 6.1.3

I have random post video which will show videos randomly

Controller

```
  def index
    @videos = Video.all
    @random_videos = Video.where.not(id: @video).all.sample(10)
  end
```

views

```
<center>
<div class="container col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <Strong><h1>30 sec Work, 20 sec Rest</h1></Strong>
    <hr>
      <% if @random_videos.blank? %>
      <% else %>
        <% @random_videos.take(10).each do |random_video| %>
        <h3><%= random_video.title %></h3>
        <% end %>
      <% end %> <br>
</div>
</center>
```

Result:

1. workout 1
2. workout 2
3. workout 3
4. workout 4
5. workout 5
6. workout 6
7. workout 7
8. workout 8
9. workout 9
10. workout 10

What i want to ask is:
Is that possible if i want to show only workout 1 in the screen for 30 second an after that move to workout 2? the screen will show different workout every 30 second.

Any gem recommend? Thank before

Comment: I don't think this is Back-end related. Then there will probably no gem for what you are looking for. It is mostly front end. What you could do is add the link to each video in a Javascript constant that could be an array or a hash. And Through a Javascript action, swap the source of the video after 30 seconds with the values (ie links of the videos) contained in the javascript constant.

Comment: To pass data from Rails to JS you can copy the links in a DIV that will be hidden (and make your JS collect those links when the DOM is fully loaded) or use data attributes. This video explains different techniques : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBk_zalHnac&t=234s (it is quite old but still valid)